# Writing a Python C extension: how to correctly load a PyListObject?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

While attempting to read a Python list filled with float numbers and to populate `real channels[7]` with their values (I'm using F2C, so real is just a typedef for float), all I am able to retrieve from it are zero values. Can you point out the error in the code below?

```
static PyObject *orbital_spectra(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  PyListObject *input = (PyListObject*)PyList_New(0);
  real channels[7], coefficients[7], values[240];
  int i;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyList_Type, &input)) {
    return NULL;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < PyList_Size(input); i++) {
    printf("%f\n", PyList_GetItem(input, (Py_ssize_t)i)); // <--- Prints zeros
  }
//....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyList_GetItem` will return a `PyObject*`.  You need to convert that to a number C understands.  Try changing your code to this:

```
printf("%f\n", PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(input, (Py_ssize_t)i)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things I see in this code.

1. You leak a reference, don't create that empty list at the beginning, it's not needed.
2. You don't need to cast to `PyListObject`.
3. `PyList_GetItem` returns a `PyObject`, not a float. Use `PyFloat_AsDouble` to extract the value.
4. If `PyList_GetItem` returns `NULL`, then an exception has been thrown, and you should check for it.

Comment: Actually, that was the 3rd point in your answer: I failed to realize that `PyList_GetItem` returns a PyObject. One other note: I have to create that empty list in the beginning, otherwise the whole thing segfaults. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: @David: where does it segfault in? PyArg_ParseTuple is supposed to extract objects without touching them (that's why it takes pointer-to-pointer).

Comment: Hm. Must be an independent bug I introduced and fixed while testing, because right now it no longer segfaults.